# WSO2 Micro Integrator language support

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Does WSO2 Micro Integrator (MI) allow custom code to be written? If yes, what all languages does WSO2 Micro Integrator support? More specifically, does it support .NET?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Micro Integrator and other WSO2 solutions are written in Java, and wso2 products natively doesn't support .NET. So if your case is to develop some extra features for wso2, you should write in Java.
For use .NET library I think, you can write, for example Custom class mediator, and wrap dll library using a JNI interface, but I wouldn't recommend this approach, and i am not sure it would be working  properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is to write a custom mediator from another language,  you can use a script mediator for this. Refer to this doc. https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/script-Mediator/

Comment: Can I use it to write .NET code as well? The reason is that my team does not have any skills other than .NET. This seems to allow use of one of these: JavaScript, Groovy, or Ruby.

Comment: No, .Net is not supported. Anyway, it will not have any complicated learning curve if you are going to write it from javascript.

Comment: No, you can't. WSO2 products, are from "Java world". But if you thinking about implementing something big, I am not sure your wso2 Micro Integrator is good choice. On the other hand, I am a .NET developer from many years, and i dont have problem with implementing own Inbound Endpoints, or other things for WSO2 in Java.